# Tensor (.tflite) Model inference returning nil using Firebase SDK on Swift

Tags: swift, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

**Preface:**

My ML (specifically NN() knowledge is very limited and i'm really only getting more and more familiar as time goes on.

Essentially, I have a model that accepts input [1, H, W, 3] (1 image, height, width, 3 channels) and SHOULD output [1, H, W, 2] (1 image, height, width, 2 channels). The idea is that with that, I'll be able to grab image data from the output with 1 of the channels in order to then convert it to an actual image which should essentially display indication AND sort of highlighting if a certain "something" existed in the input image using that 1 color channel (or the other color channel).

The model author is actively working on the model so it's nothing close to a perfect model.

**So, with that:**

I was initially using the tensorflowlite SDK to do everything but I found that official documentation, examples, and open source work wasn't even close to comparable with Firebase SDK. Plus, the actual project (currently testing this in a test environment) already uses Firebase SDK. Anyway, i was able to get some form of output, but I wasn't normalizing the image properly so the output wasn't as expected but at least there was SOMETHING.

Using [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/ios/use-custom-models) guide on Firebase, I am trying to run an inference on a tflite model.

From the below code you'll see that I have TensorFlowLite as a dependency but i'm not actually ACTIVELY using it. I have a function that uses it but the function isn't called.
So essentially you can ignore: *parseOutputTensor, coordinateToIndex*, and *enum: Constants*

Theories:

1. My modelInputs aren't set up properly.
2. I'm not correctly looking at the output
3. I'm not resizing and processing the image correctly before I use it to set the input data for inference
4. I don't know what I"m doing and i'm way off. D:

Below is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import AVFoundation
import TensorFlowLite

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var captureSesssion : AVCaptureSession!
    var cameraOutput : AVCapturePhotoOutput!
    var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    @objc let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)!
    private var previousInferenceTimeMs: TimeInterval = Date.distantPast.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
    private let delayBetweenInferencesMs: Double = 1000
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    private var button1 : UIButton = {
        var button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("button lol", for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked), for: .touchDown)
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startCamera()
        view.addSubview(button1)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(button1)
        button1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        button1.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 25)
        button1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width/3).isActive = true
        button1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func buttonClicked() {
        cameraPressed()
    }

    private func configureLocalModel() -> CustomLocalModel {
        guard let modelPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "modelName", ofType: "tflite") else { fatalError("Couldn't find the modelPath") }
        return CustomLocalModel(modelPath: modelPath)
    }

    private func createInterpreter(customLocalModel: CustomLocalModel) -> ModelInterpreter{
        return ModelInterpreter.modelInterpreter(localModel: customLocalModel)
    }

    private func setModelInputOutput() -> ModelInputOutputOptions? {
        var ioOptions : ModelInputOutputOptions
        do {
            ioOptions = ModelInputOutputOptions()
            try ioOptions.setInputFormat(index: 0, type: .float32, dimensions: [1, 512, 512, 3])
            try ioOptions.setOutputFormat(index: 0, type: .float32, dimensions: [1, 512, 512, 2])
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed to set input or output format with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return ioOptions
    }

    private func inputDataForInference(theImage: CGImage) -> ModelInputs?{
        let image: CGImage = theImage
        guard let context = CGContext(
            data: nil,
            width: image.width, height: image.height,
            bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: image.width * 4,
            space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
            bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue
        ) else { fatalError("Context issues") }

        context.draw(image, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.width, height: image.height))
        guard let imageData = context.data else { fatalError("Context issues") }

        let inputs : ModelInputs
        var inputData = Data()
        do {
            for row in 0 ..< 512 {
                for col in 0 ..< 512 {
                    let offset = 4 * (col * context.width + row)
                    // (Ignore offset 0, the unused alpha channel)
                    let red = imageData.load(fromByteOffset: offset+1, as: UInt8.self)
                    let green = imageData.load(fromByteOffset: offset+2, as: UInt8.self)
                    let blue = imageData.load(fromByteOffset: offset+3, as: UInt8.self)

                    // Normalize channel values to [0.0, 1.0]. This requirement varies
                    // by model. For example, some models might require values to be
                    // normalized to the range [-1.0, 1.0] instead, and others might
                    // require fixed-point values or the original bytes.
                    var normalizedRed = Float32(red) / 255.0
                    var normalizedGreen = Float32(green) / 255.0
                    var normalizedBlue = Float32(blue) / 255.0

                    // Append normalized values to Data object in RGB order.
                    let elementSize = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: normalizedRed)
                    var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: elementSize)
                    memcpy(&bytes, &normalizedRed, elementSize)
                    inputData.append(&bytes, count: elementSize)
                    memcpy(&bytes, &normalizedGreen, elementSize)
                    inputData.append(&bytes, count: elementSize)
                    memcpy(&bytes, &normalizedBlue, elementSize)
                    inputData.append(&bytes, count: elementSize)
                }
            }
            inputs = ModelInputs()
            try inputs.addInput(inputData)
        } catch let error {
            print("Failed to add input: \(error)")
        }
        return inputs
    }

    private func runInterpreter(interpreter: ModelInterpreter, inputs: ModelInputs, ioOptions: ModelInputOutputOptions){
        interpreter.run(inputs: inputs, options: ioOptions) { outputs, error in
            guard error == nil, let outputs = outputs else { fatalError("interpreter run error is nil or outputs is nil") }
            let output = try? outputs.output(index: 0) as? [[NSNumber]]
            print()
            print("output?[0]: \(output?[0])")
            print("output?.count: \(output?.count)")
            print("output?.description: \(output?.description)")
        }
    }


    private func gotImage(cgImage: CGImage){
        let configuredModel = configureLocalModel()
        let interpreter = createInterpreter(customLocalModel: configuredModel)
        guard let modelioOptions = setModelInputOutput() else { fatalError("modelioOptions got image error") }
        guard let modelInputs = inputDataForInference(theImage: cgImage) else { fatalError("modelInputs got image error") }
        runInterpreter(interpreter: interpreter, inputs: modelInputs, ioOptions: modelioOptions)
    }

    private func resizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let newSize = CGSize(width: targetSize.width, height: targetSize.height)

        // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: targetSize.width, height: targetSize.height)

        // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
        image.draw(in: rect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
    }

}

extension ViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate{
        func startCamera(){
            captureSesssion = AVCaptureSession()
            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSesssion)
            captureSesssion.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo;
            cameraOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            previewLayer.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.origin.x, y: view.frame.origin.y, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                return

            }
            device.focusMode = .continuousAutoFocus
            device.unlockForConfiguration()

            print("startcamera")

            if let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) {
                if captureSesssion.canAddInput(input) {
                    captureSesssion.addInput(input)
                    if captureSesssion.canAddOutput(cameraOutput) {
                        captureSesssion.addOutput(cameraOutput)
                        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                        captureSesssion.startRunning()
                    }
                } else {
                    print("issue here : captureSesssion.canAddInput")
                    _ = UIAlertController(title: "Your camera doesn't seem to be working :(", message: "Please make sure your camera works", preferredStyle: .alert)
                }
            } else {
                fatalError("TBPVC -> startCamera() : AVCaptureDeviceInput Error")
            }
        }
        func cameraPressed(){
            let outputFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA]
            let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: outputFormat)
            cameraOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)

        }

        func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
            print("got image")
//            guard let cgImageFromPhoto = photo.cgImageRepresentation()?.takeRetainedValue() else { fatalError("cgImageRepresentation()?.takeRetainedValue error") }

            guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else {
                fatalError("Error while generating image from photo capture data.")

            }

            guard let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData) else {
                fatalError("Unable to generate UIImage from image data.")
            }


            let tempImage = resizeImage(image: uiImage, targetSize: CGSize(width: 512, height: 512))
            // generate a corresponding CGImage
            guard let tempCgImage = tempImage.cgImage else {
                fatalError("Error generating CGImage")
            }

            gotImage(cgImage: tempCgImage)
        }

    @objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        } else {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Is there a question here? It's super interesting discussion but I am not clear on if you're asking a question or making a statement. Also, it's a LOT of code and some of it may be unrelated. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am also not seeing any firebase related code, so that's making it hard to understand what's being asked.

Comment: I removed a lot of irrelevant code. The rest I assume could be used to find an issue that's causing the nil result. I guess my question is, why do I get a nil output from the interpreter?

Firebase Objects: CustomLocalModel, ModelInterpreter, ModelInputOutputOptions, ModelInputs

Comment: Firebase does not have objects in that sense. If we are talking Real Time Database, Firebase has a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes#firdatasnapshot) which is the only object that's returned from Firebase with data and not generally subclassed. If you're using Firestore, the objects are [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot). Are yours subclasses? Can you include you Firebase code so we can see if that's the cause?

Comment: How are they not objects? Those 4 classes I listed above are being used as class instances. Class instances are objects. ModelOutput - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasemlmodelinterpreter/api/reference/Classes/ModelOutputs is the output's object type.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding. We are trying to help - however, the question being asked is unclear - what is the actual issue? Does your code crash? Is it providing incorrect output? If you are using the Firebase Realtime Database or Firestore for storage (as indicated by the tag) that code is not included so we don't know if that's involved or not. Are you using an existing TensorFlow model or retraining. My comment above was in regards to the the database if you are using it. If not, remove that tag and add an appropriate one like firebase-mlkit.

Comment: @Jay Dude it says it in the title. The output is nil. I'm using a local tensorflow model. If you looked at the code and the **Firebase** guide link I provided you'd see that. It's not regarding the database but Firebase isn't just the databatase. Hence why the Swift dependency is 'Firebase' not 'Firebase-MLKit'. Your above comments was in regards to many things but you said that 'Firebase only returns one object with data' and I was responding and telling you they're objects since I use the **Firebase** class instances - aka objects and they do also return data.

Comment: I found the answer nonetheless. Will be updating this when I finish this practice project

Comment: Glad you fixed it, dude. *Which* inference is returning nil was the question. It doesn't state the OUTPUT is nil, it states the inference is so it was a bit confusing. *Tensor (.tflite) Model inference returning nil using Firebase SDK on Swift*. Please post your fix as an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: What do you mean which inference is returning nil...? I'm running ONE inference. Have you glanced at the code? In the post I say ".....The idea is that with that, I'll be able to grab image data from the output..." Since i'm running an inference, with very minimal knowledge you can conclude that output is the inference result (aka what is being returned).